# Consulta SQL com tipo array no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, array, postgresql

Como filtrar esse campo do tipo *array* no PostgreSQL?

Tenho uma tabela `X` com um campo `Y` do tipo `character varying[]` com dois registros:

```
{'meeting','lunch','training','presentation'}  
{'breakfast','consulting', 'meeting'}
```

Nesse contexto como fazer uma consulta do tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y CONTAINS('lunch')
```

Comment: Tenta isso: SELECT * FROM X WHERE 'lunch' = ANY (Y);

Comment: Não me retornou nada.

Comment: Tentou `SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y @> ARRAY['lunch']::varchar[]`?

Comment: Também não retornou. O engraçado é que na própria documetação não mostrar uma query dessa.

Comment: Pode ser que seja problema nos dados. Pena que o SQLFiddle não funciona direito pra eu testar.

Comment: Tentei o SQLFiddle tb e não consegui nem mesmo criar o schema. :-(

Comment: Depois de muitos testes eu percebi uma coisa, cadas **string** estava delimitado por aspa simples. {'meeting','lunch','training','presentation'}

Sendo assim, vou editar a pergunta para o contexto que me encontrava.

As duas soluções de @cantoni e bigown estão corretas, a de cantoni com uma limitação, mas correta para a pergunta.

Comment: Pega alguém experiente no BD para te ajudar. É totalmente possível fazer esta consulta.

Comment: Essas duas soluções funcionaram:

`SELECT * FROM X WHERE 'lunch' = ANY (Y)`  
`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y @> ARRAY['lunch']::varchar[]`

Comment: @bigown, cantoni, vocês podem transformar seus comentários em respostas.

Comment: Feito @AndréHenriques. Não recebi notificação sobre seu comentário, estranho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `contains()` não vai funcionar mesmo, precisa usar uma função mais adequada, o `any()`, conforme o cantoni disse ou usar o operador que faz a busca em colunas do tipo `array`:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y @> ARRAY['lunch']::varchar[]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Array.sql).

Obviamente os dados precisam estar em formato adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Um opção é utilizar o ANY ou SOME (na verdade, SOME é um alias pra ANY).

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE 'lunch' = ANY (Y)
```

Comment: Testei com o `ANY` e funcionou, mas seria possível buscar 2 elementos?
'lunch' e  'meeting', com a versão de @bigown funciona para buscar quantos elementos.

Comment: Tenta o contrário, por favor: SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y= ANY(array['lunch','meeting'])

Comment: Pegou não.   Acho que para o um elemento seria o ANY, já para comprar vários elementos então deveria utilizar o operador `@>`

Comment: Tenta fazer um SQLFiddle com esse modelo. Fica mais fácil de fazer testes. O SQLFiddle dá uns bugs, mas já fiz funcionar para Postgres.